# Change page dynamically

Tags: php, jquery, html

```
<?php

  $go = $_GET['go'];


  if(!empty($go)) {

    if(is_file("page/$go.html")) include "page/$go.html";

    else echo "<h1>Error 404</h1><p>Strona nie odnaleziona</p><p>Warunek ?go jest niepoprawny</p>";
  }

  else include "page/start.html";

  ?>
<script>
$.get('go', function(change) {
  $('#center').load('page/<?php echo $go ?>.html');
});
</script>
```

I have somethng like this but it doesn't work. I just want that the page which is loaded (?go=name) won't refresh whole page

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, that's vulnerable to an LFI vulnerability (Local File Inclusion). Consider what happens when someone enters: http://site.com/file.php?go=../../../../../../../../etc/passwd%00

Also, you can't just echo your filename and expect it to print it out...if you want to include the contents of the page in $go and print out $go, then use:

```
$go = urldecode([$_GET['go']);
$go = str_replace("/", "", $go);
$go = "page/$go.html";
```

EDIT: Actually, if you use my above code, they could still access files in the local directory, such as .htpasswd and .htaccess, so just don't let your users include any local files. There are better ways to solve the problem you have.

As for the AJAX, follow jeroen's advice.

Comment: Good call about the security (although he *is* adding `.html` at the end...), but using something like `basename()` should be enough.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know PHP had that function. In any case if you use basename(), it would still be possible to include files in the current directory like this: http://site.com/file.php?$go=.htpasswd%00

Comment: @malfy, it´s always better to be on the safe side :-)

Comment: @jeroen: The %00 espcapes the use of his additional .html extension since PHP uses C-like strings.

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing two ajax functions, `$.get` and `.load` and you are missing an event handler.

You will need something like this:

```
$('#go').live('change', function() {
  $('#center').load('page/' + $(this).val() + '.html');
});
```

I have used `live` instead of `change` in case the `go` button is located in the refreshed section of the page.

**Note** that I am guessing that you want to refresh a section of your page based on a selection, the question / code isn´t exactly clear about that...

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want to achieve?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var getgo = '<?php echo $_GET['go']; ?>';
        if(getgo.length) {
            $('#center').load('page/'+getgo+'.html');
        }
    });
</script>
<div id="center"></div>
```

It will load the contents of *page/[your go param].html* into #center.

Comment: You don´t need any `javascript` if you're just going to load the data at initial page-load, you can just include it using `php`. Unless you want to delay loading, but that doesn´t seem to be the case here.

Comment: Yeah, I don't know why you'd want to do it, either, it's just how I interpreted the question.  However, doing it client-side would avoid the security issue of including a page on the server side named in the url parameter.

Comment: Wow, that's true! Although it does not seem that security is a concern for the OP :-)